# Using TPL to batch/de-parallelise separate invocations

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, reentrancy

Maybe the TPL isn't the right tool, but at least from one not particularly familiar with it, it seems like it ought to have what I'm looking for.  I'm open to answers that don't use it though.

Given a method like this:

```
public Task Submit(IEnumerable<WorkItem> work)
```

This can execute an expensive async operation on a collection of items.  Normally the caller batches up these items and submits as many as it can at once, and there's a fairly long delay between such batches, so it executes fairly efficiently.

However there are some occasions where no external batching happens and `Submit` gets called for a small number of items (typically only one) many times in quick succession, possibly even concurrently from separate threads.

What I'd like to do is to defer processing (while accumulating the arguments) until there has been a certain amount of time with no calls, and *then* execute the operation with the whole batch, in the originally specified order.

Or in other words, each time the method is called it should add its arguments to the list of pending items and then restart the delay from zero, such that a certain idle time is required before anything is processed.

I don't want a size limit on the batch (so I don't think [BatchBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194745(v=vs.110).aspx) is the right answer), I just want a delay/timeout.  I'm certain that the calling pattern is such that there *will* be an idle period at some point.

I'm not sure whether it's better to defer even the first call, or if it should start the operation immediately and only defer subsequent calls if the operation is still in progress.

If it makes the problem easier, I'm ok with making `Submit` return void instead of a `Task` (ie. not being able to observe when it completes).

I'm sure I can muddle together something that works like this, but it seems like the sort of thing that ought to already exist somewhere.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  (I'd prefer not to use non-core libraries, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for lack of finding anything suitable I ended up implementing something myself.  Seems to do the trick.  (I implemented it a bit more generically than shown here in my actual code, so I could reuse it more easily, but this illustrates the concept.)

```
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> _Items
    = new ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem>();
private CancellationTokenSource _CancelSource;

public async Task Submit(IEnumerable<WorkItem> items)
{
    var cancel = ReplacePreviousTasks();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _Items.Enqueue(item);
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), cancel.Token);
    if (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await RunOperation();
    }
}

private CancellationTokenSource ReplacePreviousTasks()
{
    var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var old = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _CancelSource, cancel);
    if (old != null)
    {
        old.Cancel();
    }
    return cancel;
}

private async Task RunOperation()
{
    var items = new List<WorkItem>();
    WorkItem item;
    while (_Items.TryDequeue(out item))
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    // do the operation on items
}
```

If multiple submissions occur within 250ms, the earlier ones are cancelled, and the operation executes once on all of the items after the 250ms is up (counting from the latest submit).

If another submit occurs while the operation is running, it will continue to run without cancelling (there's a tiny chance it will steal some of the items from the later call, but that's ok).

(Technically checking `cancel.IsCancellationRequested` isn't really necessary, since the `await` above will throw an exception if it was cancelled during the delay.  But it doesn't hurt, and there is a tiny window it might catch.)